# Выпадающий список меню

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #797575 no-repeat fixed;
}

p {
  background: #000000;
  color: #2d4e5d;
}


/*Выпадающее меню*/

#navigation {
  height: 70px;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative
}

#navigation ul li a {
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  background: #e3c628;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover {
  background: #766e42;
}

#navigation .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: 163px;
  background: #766e42;
  /*    display: none;*/
}

#navigation li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

#navigation .dropmenu li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Смотерть</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Мультфильмы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Илья</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Артем</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Женя</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Вопрос вот в чем:
Не могу понять, почему остается темен-желтый цвет, справа, в выпадающем меню и почему в пункте " Контакты",  пункт li ( Артем), отображается не в колонну, а будто строчный, а третий пункт li(Женя) уже отображается как надо.

Display:none Отключил специально.
Заранее благодарю за помощь в начинаниях и освоении

Comment: Залейте пожалуйста код на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RobinGold/cntagwos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `float: left;` у вас выставлен для все `li`, когда ваши `.dropmenu li` должны быть без `float`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #797575 no-repeat fixed;
}

p {
  background: #000000;
  color: #2d4e5d;
}


/*Выпадающее меню*/

#navigation {
  height: 70px;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative
}

#navigation ul.dropdown li {
  float: none;
}

#navigation ul li a {
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  background: #e3c628;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover {
  background: #766e42;
}

#navigation .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: 163px;
  background: #766e42;
  /*    display: none;*/
}

#navigation li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

#navigation .dropmenu li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Смотерть</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Мультфильмы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Илья</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Артем</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Женя</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```